# Why will shell automatically close for jailed user with 777 home?

Tags: ssh, permissions, su, home, jails

Jailed a user using https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/ on Centos7

```
sudo jk_jailuser -m -j /home/jail -v -s /bin/bash testing
sudo jk_cp -v -f /home/jail /bin/bash
```

Then made `/home/jail/home/testing` 0777 so I can sftp as my username and get files.  All working.

Then attempted to `su testing` as local user or attempted to putty in as testing, and shell instantly closed.

Changed home to 0700, and now can do so again.

Why does this happen?

Comment: you trying jail to writable root?

Comment: @sebasth  I don't understand.  Do you mind re-wording?

Comment: Is your jail root `/` writable,wWhat is the directory jail sets the root to? Your question says you set permissions to 777 for `/home/jail/home/testing` and "Changed home to 0700", you talking about the same directory?

Comment: @sebasth  Yes, same `/home/jail/home/testing` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons `ssh` and [jailkit](https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jailkit.8.html) do not allow writable root directory `/` and abort if they detect bad permissions.

For example if root is writable users could provide their own configuration files in `/etc` (and their own `/etc/passwd`) or their own dynamic libraries in `/lib` to abuse setuid binaries (or already running privileged processes in using same chroot) for privilege escalation.